# Why does Input Geometry work for one ArcGIS REST Service Map Layer but not another?

Tags: contour, arcgis-rest-api, parcel

In an effort to limit the amount of data I'm retrieving from a couple of ArcGIS REST Services (and thus avoid timeouts) I'm using the Input Geometry field to limit my results to an area much smaller than the entire dataset.

I'm using `Envelope` for **Geometry Type** and an **Input Geometry** with the following:

```json
{
  "xmin": -105.804,
  "ymin": 35.573,
  "xmax": -105.797,
  "ymax": 35.577,
  "spatialReference" : {
    "wkid" : 4326
  }
}
```

The Parcel layer returns a limited set of features that Intersect with the Envelope.

The Contours layer returns 0 features.

Am I doing something wrong or is there some restriction on the Contour layer to prevent using Input Geometries?

[image: Parcels Query]
[image: Contours Query]

Comment: Just checking, are you sure there are any contours at that location?

Comment: @Berend Well, I was going to say "Yes" because I can see them in their Tax Parcel Viewer, but I just discovered I can dig into the layers details and that a) takes me to a different ArcGIS REST Services server and b) takes me to a layer named 10FtContours instead of 2Ft... so that's strange. I'm going to try and connect to this different server and see what I get back.

Comment: @Berend Thank you for this suggestion. While I can't prove that the original MapLayer I was looking at has contours in this location or not (it does have Parcels there), your prompt for me to check led me to a different ArcGIS REST Server which does have 2Ft contours (though they seem to be mis-named 10Ft contours)

Comment: You could always load the service in ArcGIS desktop or qgis and zoom to that extent to do a visual check

Comment: @Berend That's what I was doing originally, but the original REST service I was using would always timeout. So I assumed it was because I was requesting too much data, so I tried to limit the features to the viewable extent I care about. That was then causing me to get NO data, which was confusing.

But it seems the main issue was that the service I was using is not the same as what the web map is using, so that was a poor assumption on my part. Your prompting helped me discover that.

Comment: What is the rest end point url?

Comment: @Mapperz It is http://52.37.30.30/arcgis/rest/services/PublicViewer/ which no longer seems to be responding for me. Turns out it was also the wrong ArcGIS server.